# Can this be simplified into methods?

Tags: java, exception

I have this exception handling code. I am wandering if it could be simplified into methods rather than having it in all in the main method. Or would it even be better to have separate classes? Many Thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
class ReadWrite {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            File myFile = new File("fruits.txt");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System. in );
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(myFile, true);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
            String fn = "";
            while (!fn.equals("exit")) {
                System.out.println("Please enter the fruit name or enter exit");
                fn = sc.nextLine();
                if (!fn.equals("exit")) {
                    pw.println(fn);
                }
            }
            pw.close();
            Scanner readFile = new Scanner(myFile);
            int i = 1;
            while (readFile.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println(i + ": " + readFile.nextLine());
                i++;
            }
            readFile.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); //shows all problems in list
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review (try http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: regarding `"I am wandering if it could be simplified into methods rather than having it in all in the main method"` -- Answer: yes, but you should be the one to try to do this. The main method should be short and sweet, and should mainly get your program up and running and little else. Regarding, `"Or would it even be better to have separate classes?"` -- Usually programs have more than just File IO, and File IO should be separate from the other parts of your program, yes in separate classes and often in separate packages.

Answer (score 1):

According to [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))

Single responsibility principle -> Every "thing" should have single responsibility.
So the short answer is YES, you can and you should, the long answer:

```
class ReadWrite
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        DataRequester dataRequester = new DataRequester(new ConsolePrinter());
        String myFileName = "fruits.txt";
        FruitWriter fruitWriter = new FruitWriter();
        FruitPrinter fruitPrinter = new FruitPrinter(new ConsolePrinter());

        fruitWriter.writeFruits(dataRequester, myFileName);
        fruitPrinter.printFruitsFrom(myFileName);
    }
}

interface Printer
{
    void print(String string);
}

class FileWriterFactory
{
    public FileWriter createFrom(String path)
    {
        try
        {
            return new FileWriter(path, true);
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

class ConsolePrinter implements Printer
{

    @Override
    public void print(String string)
    {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}

class DataRequester
{
    private final Printer printer;

    DataRequester(Printer printer)
    {
        this.printer = printer;
    }

    public void requestForDataOf(String type)
    {
        printer.print(String.format("Please enter the %s name or enter exit", type));
    }
}

class FruitWriter{

    public void writeFruits(DataRequester dataRequester, String myFileName)
    {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriterFactory().createFrom(myFileName);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

        String fn = "";

        while (shouldExit(fn))
        {
            dataRequester.requestForDataOf("fruit");

            fn = sc.nextLine();
            if (shouldExit(fn))
            {
                pw.println(fn);
            }
        }

        pw.close();
    }


    private static boolean shouldExit(String fn)
    {
        return !fn.equals("exit");
    }
}

class FruitPrinter{
    private final Printer printer;

    FruitPrinter(Printer printer)
    {
        this.printer = printer;
    }

    public void printFruitsFrom(String path){
        Scanner readFile = new Scanner(path);

        int line = 1;
        while (readFile.hasNextLine())
        {
            printer.print(String.format("Line %s: %s", line, readFile.nextLine()));
            line++;
        }

        readFile.close();
    }
}
```

obviously, this needs to be separated into files, file per class.
Notice how everything is vary clear now.
From just reading the main method i understand the app, I know exactly what to except from it to do.
It writes fruit.
and it prints them.

Where from? where to?
I don't care.
If i cared i would look in the implementation.

Also, look at the separation of the Printer.
My fruitPrinter does not know where he prints to, neither does he needs to know.
I gave him a printer, the printer knows how to print and that is all that matters.
If tomorrow i want to use a file printer, i would change this line:

```
FruitPrinter fruitPrinter = new FruitPrinter(new ConsolePrinter());
```

to

```
FruitPrinter fruitPrinter = new FruitPrinter(new FilePrinter());
```

And no one will know the difference!
that is two more principles from SOLID, the OCP and DIP, I suggest you read about them.